# exe file generated using .NET 3.5 cannot load dll created using .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have an exe file which was generated using .NET 3.5 version. I do not have source code of this, all I have is this exe file. This exe file loads certain dll files. One of the dll file is generated using .NET 4.5. Can this not be done ?
I get error "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded."

In my exe file config file I do have 'supportedRuntime' entries for all 3 versions

```
<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.5"/>
```

I thought by adding the above will help console applications developed older versions can load dll files developed using newer versions. Am I correct? If not, what is the solution ?

Comment: A little research would show that this issue is unavoidable as the .NET framework is not forward compatible. You'll need to compile your assembly with a framework version compatible with the target application (likely, 3.5). And no, the configuration lines won't influence the applications ability to load your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why everyone is saying this can't be done because it most certainly can be done. There are two things you need to fix about your configuration file. One is that the most preferred runtime must come first. If you put .NET 4.5 last it will try to load .NET 2.0 runtime first and if it is is installed use it. The result is a BadImageFormatException when you try to load the incompatible dll. The second issue is that .NET 4.5 was an in-place upgrade to .NET 4.0 so the syntax is a little different. The proper format is this:

```xml
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>    
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>    
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
</startup>
```

Note the use of the `sku` attribute. There's more info in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you need to use 4.0 Client Profile, for example.

Now you didn't write the exe, so you actually have no idea if it will actually work in .Net 4.5 (it may not) so this is a little dangerous. Caveat emptor.

Answer (score 1):

It-seems you need to compile new assembly reference to create DLL file, with a framework version 3.5, which is compatible with your application create with framework version 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your DotNet35.exe is locked with CLR 2, when it is launching, it uses CLR 2 which can not utilize PluginDotNet45.dll through reflection. Yes, I presume reflection is involved.

Depend on the design of DotNet35.exe, such workaround might be possible:
1. Write a new exe called DotNet45.exe using .NET Framework 4.5, and this exe will reference DotNet35.exe as a normal assembly.
2. DotNet45.exe will use some functions in DotNet35.exe to show GUI and load plugin including the ones built with .NET 4.5.

If DotNet35.exe does not have many visible functions to use, you might be able to use reflection to call some private functions after inspecting though ILSpy.

Another approach is to decompile DotNet35.exe into C# codes, then compile with .NET 4.5.